# Ошибка при передвижении камеры в эдиторе и при проигровывании анимации. Unity Editor

Tags: unity3d, анимация, fps

Ошибка при передвижении камеры в эдиторе и при проигровывании анимации.
У меня в сцене нет никаких скриптов. При передвижении камеры эдитора на ПКМ в консоли ошибка и фпс падает до 5-10 (СЦЕНА НЕ ЗАПУЩЕНА):

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Handles.BeginLineDrawing (UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 matrix, System.Boolean dottedLines, System.Int32 mode) (at <3b74787e58694cdda2c241162159b3b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Handles.DrawLine (UnityEngine.Vector3 p1, UnityEngine.Vector3 p2, System.Boolean dottedLine) (at <3b74787e58694cdda2c241162159b3b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Handles.DrawLine (UnityEngine.Vector3 p1, UnityEngine.Vector3 p2) (at <3b74787e58694cdda2c241162159b3b7>:0)
UnityEditor.CameraEditorUtils.DrawFrustumGizmo (UnityEngine.Camera camera) (at <3b74787e58694cdda2c241162159b3b7>:0)
UnityEditor.CameraEditor.RenderGizmo (UnityEngine.Camera camera) (at <3b74787e58694cdda2c241162159b3b7>:0)
UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderPipelineManager:DoRenderLoop_Internal(RenderPipelineAsset, Camera[], IntPtr, AtomicSafetyHandle)
```

Edit: При чем если открыть в Юнити окно с игрой на полный экран то все лаги пропадают при этом анимация продолжает проигрываться. Вот весь скрин юнити https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6s77.jpg

Comment: если вы думаете что дело в юнити, то переустановите его (кеш почистить не забудьте)

Comment: Я пересел на новый пк и на 19 версию юнити, так что дело скорее всего не в нём.

Comment: если сцена НЕ запущена и уже ошибки (лучше дайте скрин) скорее всего в юнити дело

Comment: Скрин прикрепил. Использовал High Render PipeLine

Comment: а у вас нет своих обработчиклв доя камеры и тп?

Comment: В каком смысле обработчики для камеры? Если пресет, то пресет самый стандартный который сразу автоматом создается как Universal Render PipeLine. Пресет назначил в настройках. Но в сцене ещё есть типо *Заркало* с текстурой которая захватывает камеру.

Answer (score 0):

> СЦЕНА НЕ ЗАПУЩЕНА

И что? Разве код не может проигрываться в не запущеной сцене? Если в сцене нет твоих скриптов, это же не значит, что нет стандартных компонентов юнити (они тоже скрипты). Один из таких скриптов явно ссылается на объект, который ты удалил. Не объект анимации ли это? Если нет можно найти виноватого поочерёдно отключая всё на сцене.